# PendingIntent to cancel opened Activity

Tags: android

I have two activities, Activity 1 is a listview, when you click on one of the item it will open activity 2. I use the notification when the Activity 1 is **not** active by using Dynamic broadcast receiver, so the user will get the notification when the Activity 1 is not active and when Activity 2 is active. Now my problem is when the user is on activity 2 and he gets the notification and clicks on it, a new Activity 1 will be opened, what I really need is to close Activity 2 and open Activity 1, can you please tell me how can I do this?

```
private void prepNotification(Context context, String msg) {

    Resources r = context.getResources();
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context,
            TestNotification.class),  
       PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT/*I tried many other options none of which seems to work */);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setTicker("New Notif").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("New Notif").setContentText(msg)
            .setContentIntent(pi).setAutoCancel(true).build();

    showBackgroundNotification(context, 0, notification);

}

private void showBackgroundNotification(Context context, int requestCode, Notification notification) {
    Intent i = new Intent(ACTION_SHOW_NOTIFICATION);
    i.putExtra("REQUEST_CODE", requestCode);
    i.putExtra("NOTIFICATION", notification);

    context.sendOrderedBroadcast(i, PERM_PRIVATE, null, null, Activity.RESULT_OK,
            null, null);
}
```

Edit 1

Both activities are hosting fragment, not sure if that matters though.

Answer (score 1):

```
Add this intent flag.



 Intent a = new Intent(context,
                TestNotification.class);
            a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
     a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     a.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, a),
```

Comment: Tried it, same thing, btw there are some syntax errors and the PendingIntent was also wrong, fixed it with the same result.

Comment: Update my intent flag. Please try it,this will solve your issue.

Comment: I jut did, Same thing.